# How to use Subnetid parameter with New-AzContainerGroup Powershell Cmdlet?

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-container-instances

I am testing creating an azure container instance group via an automation job which works, but in order to meet my requirements I need it to be attached to one of my configured VNETS, rather than using a public IP.
According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.containerinstance/new-azcontainergroup?view=azps-7.3.2) I need to create a hash table for the subnet ID, which I've attempted to do here, in the $hash variable

> `Name                           Value`
>
> `----                           -----`
>
> `ManagedServices                /subscriptions/{My-subscriptionID}/resourceGroups/{My-Resource-Group}/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/{My-VNET}/subnets/{My-Subnet}`

However, whenever I run the command attempting to pass the $hash variable in, I receive the following error

> New-AzContainerGroup : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'SubnetId'.

Here is the exact command that I am using

`New-AzContainerGroup -ResourceGroupName Dev-Test -Name mycontainer -Image najarramsada/phpipamscanagent -OsType Linux -DnsNameLabel phpipamtest -SubnetId $hash`

I am expecting this to run and create a container in my chosen subnet but instead I am getting the error indicating that the parameter doesn't exist. I am also not certain I created my hash table correctly as I've never used them before.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you are receiving indicates that you have spelled the parameter incorrectly.

> New-AzContainerGroup : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'SubbnetId'.

```
New-AzContainerGroup -ResourceGroupName Dev-Test -Name mycontainer -Image najarramsada/phpipamscanagent -OsType Linux -DnsNameLabel phpipamtest -SubnetId $hash
```

When creating your hashtable it looks as though you may need to use the following:

```
$hash = @{
    Id = 'resourceId'
    Name = 'FriendlyName'
}
```

Taken from the NOTES section here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.containerinstance/new-azcontainergroup?view=azps-7.3.2#notes

Comment: Not sure how I got the spelling wrong that time, but after correcting it it is still giving me the same error of parameter not found. I've edited the post to reflect that the error still exists with the correct spelling.